# Magento Template Hints won't turn off on only one page. Debugging

Tags: magento, caching

I am having a strange problem whereby my template path hints will not deactivate on a single only.

Previously to this I was having a strange error where the contact form on the page would submit, but would display it's success message on the product page.

This issue seemed to be resolved after clearing the cache (we use APC cache, which was also cleared). The thing was I submitted the contact form while the template hint where still on, and since then have been unable to turn them off for that page only.

I have tried the usual procedures of going up and down stairs with the cache, and also deleting the contents of the cache folder from the terminal.

Has anyone any suggestions where I would even begin to debug this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start by dropping into the base template class

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php
```

and figuring out why the `getShowTemplateHints` method is returning true on that page

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php
public function getShowTemplateHints()
{
    if (is_null(self::$_showTemplateHints)) {
        self::$_showTemplateHints = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_DEBUG_TEMPLATE_HINTS)
            && Mage::helper('core')->isDevAllowed();
        self::$_showTemplateHintsBlocks = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_DEBUG_TEMPLATE_HINTS_BLOCKS)
            && Mage::helper('core')->isDevAllowed();
    }
    return self::$_showTemplateHints;
}
```

Or, of it's returning `false`, why does the base template class still reach the rendering point.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php
if ($this->getShowTemplateHints()) {
                echo <<<HTML
    <div style="position:relative; border:1px dotted red; margin:6px 2px; padding:18px 2px 2px 2px; zoom:1;">
    <div style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; padding:2px 5px; background:red; color:white; font:normal 11px Arial;
    text-align:left !important; z-index:998;" onmouseover="this.style.zIndex='999'"
    onmouseout="this.style.zIndex='998'" title="{$fileName}">{$fileName}</div>
HTML;
                if (self::$_showTemplateHintsBlocks) {
                    $thisClass = get_class($this);
                    echo <<<HTML
    <div style="position:absolute; right:0; top:0; padding:2px 5px; background:red; color:blue; font:normal 11px Arial;
    text-align:left !important; z-index:998;" onmouseover="this.style.zIndex='999'" onmouseout="this.style.zIndex='998'"
    title="{$thisClass}">{$thisClass}</div>
HTML;
                }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Really helpful. However, that problem seemed to have resolved itself. I am still having the strange issue with the contact success message, but it has now moved to a different part of the site. Any help you could offer would be appreiciated  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061576/magento-contact-form-success-message-is-moving-around-my-website-debugging

Answer (score 1):

Refreshing the cache solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

After checking each store view for template hints and clearing server and local cache I cleared the cache again and then restarted apache.